# AutoResetEvent use issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, autoresetevent

I'm trying to use an AutoResetEvent object to block the thread until the async. download of a WebClient is done.

My problem is that once I call WaitOne(), the thread just locks there and VS never reaches the breakpoint in the DownloadComplete event handler method.

Here's my code

```
//Class used to pass arguments to WebClient's events...

public class RunArgs
{
    public JobInfo jobInfo;
    public int jobTotal;
    public int jobIndex;
    public AutoResetEvent AutoResetEventObject;
}

List<JobInfo> jl = ConfigSectionWrapper.GetAllJobs();

int jobAmount = jl.Count;
int jobIndex = 0;

RunArgs args = new RunArgs();
args.jobTotal = jl.Count;


foreach (JobInfo ji in jl)
{


    if (ji.enabled == "0")
    {
        args.jobIndex++;
        continue;
    }

    try
    {
        args.jobIndex++;
        args.jobInfo = ji;

        appLog.Source = ji.eventSource;
        appLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Started job {0}...", ji.jobName),         EventLogEntryType.Information);
        ji.fullFileName = string.Format(ji.reportFileName, string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')));
        ji.fullFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", ji.downloadDirectory, ji.fullFileName);

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            AutoResetEvent notifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            args.AutoResetEventObject = notifier;
            wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(args.jobInfo.reportURL), args.jobInfo.fullFileName, args); //Pass the args params to event handler...
            notifier.WaitOne();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        appLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Error starting report execution: {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        DeleteFile(ji.fullFileName);
    }

}

private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    RunArgs args = (RunArgs)e.UserState;

    //Do things....

    args.AutoResetEventObject.Set();  
 }
```

So I instantiate ***notifier*** with false in the constructor, because I don't want its status to be signaled already. Unless I'm reading MSDN wrong ?

Anything obviously wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
private AutoResetEvent notifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Now the main loop looks like:

```
        foreach (JobInfo ji in jl)
        {
            if (ji.enabled == "0")
            {
                args.jobIndex++;
                continue;
            }

            args.jobInfo = ji;
            Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startDownload));
            t.Start(args);
            notifier.WaitOne();
        }

private void startDownload(object startArgs)
    {
        RunArgs args = (RunArgs)startArgs;

        try
        {
            args.jobIndex++;
            appLog.Source = args.jobInfo.eventSource;
            appLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Started job {0}...", args.jobInfo.jobName), EventLogEntryType.Information);
            args.jobInfo.fullFileName = string.Format(args.jobInfo.reportFileName, string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')));
            args.jobInfo.fullFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", args.jobInfo.downloadDirectory, args.jobInfo.fullFileName);

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(args.jobInfo.reportURL), args.jobInfo.fullFileName, args); //Pass the args params to event handler...

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            appLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Error starting report execution: {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            DeleteFile(args.jobInfo.fullFileName);
            notifier.Set();
        }

    }
```

So now the AutoResetEvent is blocking the main thread but **t** can successfully trigger the **DownloadFileCompleteEvent**. And in the **DownloadFileCompleted** event, I'm obviously doing a *notifier.Set()* too.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

`WebClient` uses the `AsyncOperationManager` to manage async operations. So, make sure you are aware of how these async operations get called under different scenarios.

## Under WinForms

Under a `WinForm` application `AsyncOperationManager` uses the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. As @Michael says, the `WaitOne()` call blocks the main form thread from firing the `DownloadCompleted` event. In `WinForms` the `DownloadCompleted` is executed on the main `WinForm` thread.

So, remove the `notifier.WaitOne()` and it should work. `DownloadCompleted` needs to be called by the main window thread (presumably, the one which you're blocking with `WaitOne()`).

## Under Console applications

Under a `Console` type application the `AsyncOperationManager` uses `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` and the `DownloadCompleted` is executed asynchronously by a thread form the threadpool.

There is no issue with calling `notifier.WaitOne()` under a `Console` app; and the code above works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any documentation to support this, but looking at the WebClient code in Reflector, it appears that the events are raised on the main thread, not the background thread. Since your main thread is blocking when you call `notifier.WaitOne()`, the event handler never gets called.

If the example you provided accurately represents your code, there's absolutely no need to use `wc.DownloadFileAsync()` instead of `wc.DownloadFile()`. That `notifier.WaitOne()` call ultimately makes this into a synchronous operation. If you're looking for a true asynchronous operation, you'll have to do this differently.

Comment: Yes, this is an old project I worked on months ago and I think there was a reason I did not use DownloadFile() (sync). I think the timeout on it cannot be extended to my needs (I'm dowloading SSRS reports which can take 5-10 mins to finish)

Comment: You'll need to rewrite this. You'll need to store off the `WebClient` instance (remove the `using` statement) and call `Dispose` on it later (e.g. when your event handler gets called). And expect the event on the main thread.

Comment: So Brian, then you see nothing wrong with the code I posted ?

Comment: It depends if your using WinForms or a Console application; because the `AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext` that `WebClient` uses is different under each scenario. The code will fail to signal under a WinForms application; but your code will work under a Console application.